# Combine an array to string in PHP

Tags: php

I have a below array in PHP

```
$arrOrders['remains'] = 'ASC';
$arrOrders['rate']    = 'DESC';
```

How can I use combine to a string like just with native function?

```
$str = 'remain ASC, rate DESC';
```

Comment: ever considered to use `foreach` to handle an array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$a = array(
    'remains' => 'ASC',
    'rate'      => 'DSC'
);  

echo implode(', ', array_map(function($v1, $v2) {
    return sprintf('%s %s', $v1, $v2);
}, array_keys($a), array_values($a)));
// remains ASC, rate DSC
```

Comment: are you always use all PHP function you know for the every simple operation?

Comment: +1 for use of functions, anyone know how would this preform vs the simple foreach HL. posted?

Comment: Not really - but I must admit that I like the functional approach on arrays. It's a matter of taste...

Comment: it's matter of bloating your code, dude. unnecessarily bloating.

Comment: Don't worry so much, because I want to have a approach like that... I know if I care about performance I could be consider with just loop. :)

Comment: @Blem: I don't think there is a noticeable difference when used on the given use case (which most likely is creating an `ORDER BY` string). If this is run 100000 times in one request the native `foreach`-solution will be much faster I suspect.
When used over very large arrays it might be interesting if the slower iteration of `foreach` is leveled by the `array_keys()` and `array_values()` calls.

Comment: @Blem it actually does 4 loops where only one neeed

Comment: I test the accepted solution compared to a single foreach and it's more slow. Anyway I would never think to this solution :)

Answer (score 3):

use a foreach and implode()

```
foreach ($arrOrders as $key => $val) {
$temp[] = "$key $val";
}
$order = implode(',', $temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$string = '';
foreach($arrOrders as $key => $value)
   $string = $string . "$key $value, ";
$string  = rtrim($string, ', '); // cut the last comma at the end of the string

echo $string // remains ASC, rate DESC
```

Comment: I'll +1 it anyway now, as it's the only sensible answer here.

Comment: yeah, sense of community, as you said. this very community is a sick one. almost every answer is unusable or propagationg whatever bad practice. that's why I am too strict with votes. it is a custome here to upvote FOR NOTHING, just for a sympathy. Ever complained for the unjust upvote?

Comment: LOL, so, you have never complained. I thought so. it's only downvotes your concern :)

Comment: no. as i said already, this site suffer from huge lack of downvotes.

Comment: that's impossible. most of them do care only of votes, not of knowledge

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), but it dose not include the keys, but the first comment on the page is a function for including keys

```
/**
 * Implode an array with the key and value pair giving
 * a glue, a separator between pairs and the array
 * to implode.
 * @param string $glue The glue between key and value
 * @param string $separator Separator between pairs
 * @param array $array The array to implode
 * @return string The imploded array
 */
function array_implode( $glue, $separator, $array ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $array ) ) return $array;
    $string = array();
    foreach ( $array as $key => $val ) {
        if ( is_array( $val ) )
            $val = implode( ',', $val );
        $string[] = "{$key}{$glue}{$val}";

    }
    return implode( $separator, $string );

}


$arrOrders = array(
    'remains' => 'ASC',
    'rate'      => 'DSC'
);
$str = array_implode( ' ', ', ', $arrOrders);
```

Comment: do you get an error or something? are you sure you used it correct, it is working fine for me

Comment: @vietean ever considered possibility **to learn** from that code, not just copypaste it?